# How to update the NodeJS version in linux? (Issue occurs when trying to install jsreport-pdf-password)

Tags: node.js, installation, node-modules, nvm

```
2019-04-04T04:34:49.035Z - error: Error when loading extension Error: The module '/media/vishesh/Disc/working/examples/jsreport_pdf_password_install_tryout/node_modules/jsreport-pdf-password/node_modules/hummus/binding/hummus.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
Error: The module '/media/vishesh/Disc/working/examples/jsreport_pdf_password_install_tryout/node_modules/jsreport-pdf-password/node_modules/hummus/binding/hummus.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

I have tried downgrading node version using nvm. I have successfully done it and reduce to the required version (i.e)8.9.1. Thus when i check the command "node -v" i get 8.9.1.

But when i check "nodejs -v" i only get 11.9.0. Thus the above mentioned error occurred. I am unable to identify how to change the nodejs version also ? Any ideas ?

Also, i have tried installing "jsreport-pdf-password" with same version 11.9.0 in node and nodejs in a completely different folder and also by deleting the node_modules. Still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading node version using the command `nvm install 8.9.1`, it will download that version but won't use it. To use version 8.9.1 you have to run another command `nvm use 8.9.1`. Then your node version manager will start to use 8.9.1.

Comment: I have not only downgraded. I did use the nvm use commad. Infact i even ran this command to set default version "nvm alias default 8.9.1".

Comment: Which version of `nvm` are you using? You can check nvm version by command `nvm version`. Install the latest version of `nvm` and then retry `nvm use 8.9.1`.

Comment: I am using the latest version installed 1week back. The version is "11.9.0".

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I searched in stackoverflow for a while and got in a post that node is the alias used by npm for nodejs. The nodejs is alias of nodejs version that the ubuntu os installs. Thus i removed the nodejs using this command "sudo apt-get remove nodejs".

Then i used nvm and set 7.10.0 as default node version. Later installed the package jsreport-pdf-password and ran the code. Now there was no error in run time regarding any version missmatch.

As far as the package is conserned it requires node version 7 and anything above or below, the error in question occurs. I tried to even rebuild the package at a later version but it did not solve the issue. Thus i recommend not to use this package if your node version is greater than 7.